# Changing the target of a `whenever` block from the inside

Tags: concurrency, erlang, reactive-programming, raku, rakudo

The following code attempts to react to one `Supply` and then, based on the content of some message, change its mind and react to messages from a different `Supply`.  It's an attempt to provide similar behavior to [Supply.migrate](https://docs.raku.org/routine/migrate) but with a bit more control.

```raku
my $c1 = Supplier.new;
my $c2 = Supplier.new;

my $s = supply {
    my $currently-listening-to = $c1.Supply;
    my $other-var = 'foo';
    whenever $currently-listening-to {
        say "got: $_";
        if .starts-with('3') {
            say "listening to something new";
            $currently-listening-to = $c2.Supply;
            $other-var = 'bar';
            say $other-var;
        }
    }
}

$s.tap;

for ^7 {
    $c1.emit: "$_ from \$c1";
    $c2.emit: "$_ from \$c2";
}
sleep 10;
```

If I understand the semantics of `supply` blocks correctly (highly doubtful!), this block should have exclusive and mutable access to any variables declared inside the `supply` block.  Thus, I expected this to get the first 4 values from `$c1` and then switch to `$c2`.  However, it doesn't.  Here's the output:

```
ot: 0 from $c1
got: 1 from $c1
got: 2 from $c1
got: 3 from $c1
listening to something new
bar
got: 4 from $c1
got: 5 from $c1
got: 6 from $c1
```

As that output shows, changing `$other-var` worked just as I expected it to, but the attempt to change `$currently-listening-to` failed (silently).

Is this behavior correct?  If so, what am I missing about the semantics of `supply` blocks/other constructs that explains this behavior?  I got the same results with `react` blocks and when using a `Channel` instead of a `Supply`, so the behavior is consistent across several multiple concurrency constructs.

(In the interest of avoiding an X-Y problem, the use case that triggered this question was an attempt implement Erlang-style error handling.  To do so, I wanted to have a supervising `supply` block that listened to its children and could kill/re-launch any children that got into a bad state.  But that means listening to the new children – which led directly to the issue described above.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I tend to consider `whenever` as the reactive equivalent of `for`. (It even supports the `LAST` loop phaser for doing something when the tapped `Supply` is `done`, as well as supporting `next`, `last`, and `redo` like an ordinary `for` loop!) Consider this:

```
my $x = (1,2,3);
for $x<> {
    .say;
    $x = (4,5,6);
}
```

The output is:

```
1
2
3
```

Because at the setup stage of a `for` loop, we obtain an iterator, and then work through that, not reading `$x` again on each iteration. It's the same with `whenever`: it taps the `Supply` and then the body is invoked per `emit` event.

Thus another `whenever` is needed to achieve a tap of the next `Supply`, while simultaneously closing the tap on the current one. When there are just two `Supply`s under consideration, the easy way to write it is like this:

```
my $c1 = Supplier.new;
my $c2 = Supplier.new;

my $s = supply {
    whenever $c1 {
        say "got: $_";
        if .starts-with('3') {
            say "listening to something new";
            # Tap the next Supply...
            whenever $c2 {
                say "got: $_";
            }
            # ...and close the tap on the current one.
            last;
        }
    }
}

$s.tap;

for ^7 {
    $c1.emit: "$_ from \$c1";
    $c2.emit: "$_ from \$c2";
}
```

Which will produce:

```
got: 0 from $c1
got: 1 from $c1
got: 2 from $c1
got: 3 from $c1
listening to something new
got: 3 from $c2
got: 4 from $c2
got: 5 from $c2
got: 6 from $c2
```

(Note that I removed the `sleep 10` because there's no need for it; we aren't introducing any concurrency in this example, so everything runs synchronously.)

Clearly, if there were a dozen `Supply`s to move between then this approach won't scale so well. So how does `migrate` work? The key missing piece is that we can obtain the `Tap` handle when working with `whenever`, and thus we are able to close it from outside of the body of that `whenever`. This is exactly how `migrate` works (copied from the standard library, with comments added):

```
method migrate(Supply:D:) {
    supply {
        # The Tap of the Supply we are currently emitting values from
        my $current;
        # Tap the Supply of Supply that we'll migrate between
        whenever self -> \inner {
            # Make sure we produce a sensible error
            X::Supply::Migrate::Needs.new.throw
                unless inner ~~ Supply;
            # Close the tap on whatever we are currently tapping
            $current.close if $current;
            # Tap the new thing and store the Tap handle
            $current = do whenever inner -> \value {
                emit(value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In short: you don't change the target of the `whenever`, but rather start a new `whenever` and terminate the previous one.

Comment: ”I tend to consider `whenever` as the reactive equivalent of `for`". Thanks, that's very helpful – I was thinking of `supply`/`whenever` as the reactive equivalent of `for`/`when`, so I was expecting to be able to change the "condition" of the `whenever` the way I can change the one for the `when`.  But I see now that `whenever` is actually doing the (reactive) "iteration", not just matching on the iteration's result the way `when` does

Comment: Indeed. The equivalent to `supply` in iterable space is `gather`. For example, one could do `gather for @outers -> @inners { for @inners -> $value { take $value; } }`, producing a result iterable from multiple others.